# How to unzip a file in windows phone (using Visual Studio Apache Cordova Community)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova, windows-mobile, unzip, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to download and unzip a file in my app, I download successfully using **File Transfer** Plugin, But I can not find a plugin for **unzip** a file, There is a plugin which supports for IOS and Android But not for **windows phone**...

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not available at this time (I've looked!) my solution was to download each file individually instead of wrapping them into a zip. A better solution is to create your own plugin that can work with Windows.

For Android and iOS, this plugin works (tested)
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip

If you're using a Cordova project you can go to config.xml and via the plugins tab -> custom -> then paste this link.

If you can't do it this way use the command line to add.

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip
```

Comment: The plugin clearly says that it only works for iOS and Android, he needs a plugin that works for Windows Phone too.

Comment: @jHogen My bad, I've updated the reply to include the fact that it only supports iOS and Android